Can't import cubing.js in node discord bot
I was trying to import the cubing.js module in nodejs so I can use in in my discord.js bot. However when I use the following import const {randomScrambleForEvent } = require('cubing/scramble') I run in to the following error 'Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './scramble' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\findh\Downloads\testcode\node_modules\cubing\package.json'.
I have imported other modules and have not gotten such an error. I made sure the module is imported by running npm i cubing. However I can't seem to fix this issue
Here is the complete code for the bot
`const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const {randomScrambleForEvent } = require('cubing/scramble')

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction === 'ping') {
        const scramble = await randomScrambleForEvent("333");
        await interaction.reply(scramble);
    }
});

client.login(BOT-TOKEN);`

I have also looked through the module itself. This is a part of the package.json file that seem relevant. I have looked through the documentation which mentions npm but I am unsure how to proceed. https://js.cubing.net/cubing/
  "exports": {
    "./alg": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/alg/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/alg/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./bluetooth": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/bluetooth/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/bluetooth/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./kpuzzle": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/kpuzzle/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/kpuzzle/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./notation": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/notation/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/notation/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./protocol": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/protocol/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/protocol/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./puzzle-geometry": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/puzzle-geometry/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/types/puzzle-geometry/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./puzzles": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/puzzles/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/types-geometry/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./scramble": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/scramble/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/scramble/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./search": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/search/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/search/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./stream": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/stream/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/stream/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./twisty": {
      "import": "./dist/lib/cubing/twisty/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/lib/cubing/twisty/index.d.ts"
    }
  }


Cubing.js is ESM-only package, but your code is using CommonJS
If it's critical for you to use this library - currently the only option is to use ESM modules:
Add to your package.json:
"type": "module"

Replace all imports by following example:
Before:
const { randomScrambleForEvent } = require('cubing/scramble');

After
import { randomScrambleForEvent } from 'cubing/scramble';


More about migration from CommonJS to ESM modules
